# Can we manually add one entry into dynamic drop down list, If then how in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a student, student_parent and address_detail table i want to add student and it's parent(Father and Mother) address in address_detail table, I have folowing relation between tables

**Student:-**
has_many :student_parents
has_many :address_details

**Student_parent:**
belongs_to :student
has_many :address_detail

**address_detail:**
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :student_parent

In address_detail form i have a drop down for only Father and mother i want to add student entry manually how can i do, Here is **my address_detail form**``

```
    <%= simple_form_for @address_detail, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<div class="control-group">
  <label  class = "control-label"> Address Correspond To <abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.collection_select(:student_parent_id, student_parent_relation_collection , :id, :relation_to_student, {:prompt => true}, :required =>true  )%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :student_id, :value => current_student_id %>
  </div>
</div>
```

....
.....

Here is my Helper method for Address_correspond_to drop down method

```
# return collection of parent relation to student
```

def student_parent_relation_collection

```
if current_user != nil
  student =  Student.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  logger.info "student_is = #{student}"
  if student != nil
  return  StudentParent.find_all_by_student_id(student)
 end
end
```

end

current OutPut is 
Father
Mother

I want Out 
Student
Father
Mother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class AddressDetail < ActiveRecord::Base

  def student_and_parents
    [student, student_parent]
  end

end
```

Then, in the view you can either refer to

```
address_detail.student_and_parents
```

or in User

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :students
  has_many :student_parents, :through => :students

  def students_and_parents
    [students, student_parents].compact.flatten
  end

end
```

you can refer to

```
current_user.try(:students_and_parents)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if current_user
  student =  Student.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  return [student] + student.student_parents if student
end
```